# Xcode cannot run using the selected device

Tags: xcode4

This is the message while trying to run under XCode 4 (it used to work under XCode 3):

No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I have profiles for my device for this app... where should I be looking to correct this?

[image]

Comment: The answer by JRod58 in this thread helped me figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874341/no-provisioned-ios-devices-are-available-with-a-compatible-ios-version

Comment: I just got this error after unplugging my test device and then plugging it back in, with no other changes. I solved it by simply restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're asking **where to find it**:

In XCode 4 there is a new button - look for the big

> "Organizer button"

which is at the TOP RIGHT.

Physically connect your device and then click Devices. It seems that the new "Organizer button" is one of the "most-missed" things in the transition to XCode4.

Note, the questioner is asking: "**WHERE** should I be looking to correct this?"

Comment: Nope... the provisioning profile is there, and as indicated, it used to work in XC3... now what do I do?

Comment: Devices screenshot:  http://imgur.com/EDbD6

What do you want to see in the Config Utility?

Comment: Thanks Joe... that did it!  I haven't a clue how I got those profiles farkeled up, but I sure did (probably when I was a very new newbie!).

Answer (score 62):

The problem is that your iOS Deployment Target in Project-> Build Settings is different from the current version of iOS on your real device.

Comment: I had a similar WTF moment with my iPhone connected... The deployment target device family was set to iPad. :(

Comment: Product -> Destination -> Choose device/simulator

Answer (score 7):

I was having extra trouble because of my Enterprise License, but still updated the iPads.  I didn't have to change anything in the Build Settings to lower.  But the main thing that I had a problem with was in the Organizer I needed to hit "Use for Development" button.

Kind of an old post, and may not be the best way or a rookie thing to miss but wanted to help anyone out.

Comment: Despite developing on the same device for over 2 years, my device had also dropped out of developer mode and I had to hit "Use for Development" again in the Organizer.

Comment: thanks heaps for posting this Alex.  Saved me a sleepless night trying to figure this out.  The error message really gave no clue that this might be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

My problem similar to those above were related to having the deployment target set too high for the version installed on the phone. Would be nice if it gave a more useful error message. I spent hours messing with my provisioning profile trying to fix it, when the real problem was the older version of the software on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The reason was simply, that my ipad had not been update to version 4.3.

Comment: Same here… Was getting the same error. Upgraded to 4.3 and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me for iOS5 with xcode 4.2.
The answer is to go into organiser, select your device, and press the "Develop with this device" button (or similar wording).
Then go back and build, and it should work..

Comment: I am not able to find this option. Please help me find it.

Comment: @Nitish: You need to plug in your iPhone, and go into Organiser. I can't give you a scrfeenshot, because I've already associated my iPhone. Under 'Devices', select your iPhone. On the right of the screen, under 'Provisioning', there should be a button "Develop with this device".

Comment: I am not having any such option. I am using xCode 4.0.1 with ios4.3 and deploying it on ios5.0.1(ipad2). Please check my[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936967/running-application-from-ios4-3-on-ios-5-0).

Answer (score 1):

I received this error while having an iPad properly connected.

Some info:

- Ipad iOS version: 4.2.1
- XCode 4.2
- XCode project created with "iOS Application / Empty Application" template.

The problem was that I had to specify the "iOS Deployment Target" to 4.2 in **more than one place**!

That is, both in the "Build Settings" and in the "Summary".

Very odd, and definitely another XCode4 annoyance.

Comment: +1 to this, I currently support 2nd gen devices (they can only go up to 4.2.1) and needed to look in "Build Settings" (select all at top left) under "Deployment" at the bottom of the section there is "iOS Deployment Target" field, setting that to 4.2 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in Organizer  - "Could not support development.". I tried rebooting the iOS device and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that the Executable File (also known as CFBundleExecutable) in the Info.plist file is set to **${EXECUTABLE_NAME}** as opposed to any hardcoded value. This will ensure that even if you change your project name or target name or scheme name, that it still works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the proper version of iOS.in my case it is iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support
GOTO --> XCode Preferences -> Downloads --> Component
there are all updates available for your iOS click Install.

This is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error can also come about if the "Product Name" in your target's build settings does not match the value of "CFBundleExecutable" in your info.plist

It looks like to me this is the general error Apple gives if the executable is not installed correctly on the device. When the debugger tries to attach it looks for the executable name and if it's not there they give this error. Touch one to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build option and select valid compiler.

Answer (score -2):

Chose your right iOS Deployment version

Comment: This answer is useless, as theres no details to it, and its already one of the answers.