# No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to test my app on an iPhone 3G, however I'm getting this error:

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Note that:

- The 3G has version 4.2.1 of iOS installed
- The iOS deployment target is set to version 4.2
- The device has valid development profiles installed
- I'm using the latest Xcode 4

I'm at a loss.  Can anyone help?

Tim

Comment: Sounds more likely to be a provisioning problem than one with the OS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this.

If anyone else has this problem then it might be useful to know that Xcode now creates applications for ARM7 by default.

To support the iPhone 3G and other arm6 devices, you need to specify arm6 and arm7 in in the Architectures list, and set the device requirements to only arm6 in the plist.

Comment: Good answer
(And some padding characters because "Good answer" wasn't enough!)

Comment: Where exactly is this setting? In a fresh set-up of Xcode 4.2 I can see 'Valid Architectures' which has defaulted to  'armv6 armv7',  and I see a 'Archtectures' which seems to be set to some kind of substitution variable: '$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)' which shows as 'Standard (armv7)'. Best way to change this?

Comment: There are detailed instructions and warnings about adding armv6 to architectures of xcode 4.2+ at [stack overflow article] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5)

Answer (score 97):

Solved this problem by closing and re-opening xcode.

> Xcode... it's the new Windows.

Comment: Mu Ha Ha Ha! that was really funny! :D :D

Comment: Damn!  that worked for me as well, and the bottom help about 'Use for Development' (it is one of my testers devices) was spot on.

Comment: I had the same issue, and had to go as far as restarting my mac before it would show my iphone as a build target.

Comment: Hah after 4 years and 4 versions of iOS, this is *still* the right answer.

Answer (score 44):

Try clicking "Use for Development" on your device in the Xcode Organizer. I got this same error and that was the only way I fixed it.

Comment: Xcode is "processing symbol files" from my iPhone... looking promising so I'm preemptively upvoting this.

Comment: I had a flaky cable connection and got this error, wobbled the cabled and could see my device reconnected in Organizer. Message cleared.

Answer (score 5):

Another observation for anyone who still has the problem after adding armv6: I found that Xcode was still listing "iOS Device" in the Scheme dropdown rather than filling in the name of my 3G. When I clicked on the dropdown, I saw that there was another slot that listed my 3G. (Presumably the "iOS Device" slot only applies to my other development device, an iPhone 4). I'm curious whether this is intended functionality, so leave a comment if you develop with multiple phones and have seen this.

Comment: With the mix of white cables pluged on the mac, I did not saw that the cable I was plugging in the iphone was one on the outlet and not the mac.

Answer (score 5):

I have Xcode 5.0, and try to build for my iPad with iOS 5.1.1. And I get the message: No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

The solution you can see in 4 step:

**(1)** Select **project settings** > **project settings** > **Info**. Choose deployment target instead of 7.0 i.e. 6.1.

[image]

**(2)** Select **project settings** > **project settings** > **Build Settings**. Change architecture . Don't compile for 64bit.
[image]

**(3)** Select **project settings** > **target settings** > **General**. Set **Deployment Target** according your device iOS version. Afterwards the device name **IPad** appear after **IOS Device** to run on.
[image]

**(4)** Finally I selected IPad.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have set the minimum required iOS to a higher version than your 3G has. Could you try to change the iOS Deployment Target in the build settings to the version of your 3G?

Comment: My iOS Deployment target is set to 4.2

Answer (score 3):

I develop on multiple devices and multiple generations of each device. Look at the scheme. In the case of an iOS 5 device, at least, if it does not have the specific device name, but instead shows iOS Device, then eject the device in iTunes and unplug the device. Plug it back in and try to run/install. The device name should show up and the device should have a green dot in Organizer and everyone will be happy. I believe the 3G iPhone just shows up as iOS Device, and I'm not sure about the 3GS, but an iPhone 4 or 4S will show its device name.  This is what I get for trying to continue supporting old iPod Touches and 3G phones with 4.2.1. At some time I'll just cut them off and move on.

Comment: Thanks! In Xcode 4.2.1 when I went into Organizer there was no green dot beside my device name in the left hand column. When I clicked on the device name (in the left column), then in the right hand side of organizer it brought up all the device info with a big button that said USE FOR DEVELOPMENT. After I clicked this button it then showed up in the drop down and I was able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, i understand your settings right. But, the rules are:

- Base SDK Version >= Development device iOS version
- Deployment Target version = Lowest iOS version to be supported.

Hence, i guess, setting base SDK version equal or above 4.2.1 might help.

Comment: The base SDK version is set to 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

i also get this case:
when i reset iphone, plugin to xcode again, xcode dont recognized iphone in schema, iphone still have full provision
I go to Organizer window, check device again and see that my iphone dont  have green light and have button that ask to use this device for development. Click on button and all work well again

Answer (score 2):

When I changed my app from iPhone to Universal, automatically xCode changed the **Deployment Target** from 4.3 to 6.1, my device had 6.0 so it wasn't recognized.

Changing the value back to 4.3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When the first time , your new test iOS connected to you Mac, you can't see it in the pop-up menu. only "IOS Device"
You may try From menu: Window->Organizer->Devices ; then Choose you connected iPad and click “Use for development" ; So it appears .

Answer (score 0):

In Organizer, I had to copy (drag and drop) the provisioning profile from the general 'Profiles' section to the device's 'Profile' section.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen because you've started to use your device on a computer that's never used it before. Once you've plugged in your device via USB, you'll need to choose to "trust" the device. You'll see a message like the following on the device itself:

> Your settings and data will be accessible from this computer when
>   connected via USB or Wi-Fi

Choose "Trust" when prompted, and then XCode will be able to use the device.

More info here at Apple's site:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5868

Answer (score 0):

"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

I had this same problem when trying to build on my device.
Then I realised I was using an aftermarket lead.
Changed the lead to the original iPhone lead and... Hey Presto!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem just change **iOS Device** of the following image [image] to **iPhone Retine ....**,

Answer (score -5):

I had a similar problem, with this error message: "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

I solved it by simply going to the "jump bar" and changing it from "iOS device" to iPad 6.0 Simulator."

Comment: He does not want to use a simulator