# iPhone app not runing on Real device

Tags: iphone, device

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

How do I fix this Questions.....?

Deployment Taeget :

- 4.0 Base SDK
- Latest 5.1

Comment: Have you connect any device into your MAC? Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7874341/940096)

Comment: you not added device id in provision profile. Please add device id that then install app.

Comment: Which version on XCode are u using and what is the OS on device??

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you choose the device from the list of schemes and from project settings you should have a valid certificate for debug settings

UPDATE : An also it will not list the device if its IOS is  below the deployment target