# Device Not Connected

Tags: ios, xcode, organizer

We have our sdk version is XCode 4.3.2, before upgrading to our IOS(iPhone 3) to 4.2.1; the device was connected properly and we were able to debug the application but as upgrade the ios version and when clicking to run from XCode, we encounter with following error message:

"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

And, also in the organizer our device is shown with yellow status.

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874341/no-provisioned-ios-devices-are-available-with-a-compatible-ios-version

Comment: We've checked the valid architecture as well as also in the organizer click for the button so to use the device but on clicking that button, following error message appeared : "Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC002) No such file or directory, at ‘/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-1196/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit_Utilities.m:798’"