# Xcode cannot run using the selected device - error corresponding to Xcode version?

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, device

My code was working fine till I did an update of my iphone os (it is now ios 6.1. Now I am no longer able to deploy on my device - it gives me the error "Xcode can not run using the selected device".

The same issue has appeared in many other stackoverflow questions but none of them seem to work for me. From the question at [Xcode cannot run using the selected device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382772/xcode-cannot-run-using-the-selected-device), I am thinking that the I need to upgrade Xcode. The current version = 4.5.2 - it does not show ios 6.1 as a deployment target. I will try to get the latest Xcode 4.6.2 but meanwhile I thought I would pose this question here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asumption is right : if you watch the Xcode release notes ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html ), you can see that iOS SDK 6.1 was added with Xcode 4.6.