# "Xcode cannot run using the selected device" though the architecture is correct

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing an iPad app and using an iPad 4 for the development.

Knowing this, what is the architecture - in the Build Settings for both the project and target- that I should use?

I'm currently using "Standard(armv7, armv7s)" in the architectures line, and the target and project are equal, so I can't understand why it says that it "**can't run using the selected device. Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device.**"
I've researched quite a lot, already. I tried to follow the solutions for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382772/xcode-cannot-run-using-the-selected-device) but none worked.

I also know that the iPad 4 has an armv7 architecture so is it a bug? Or should I change the architecture for some other value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure you are not trying to run on the simulator?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure... Now trying to apply the solutions given in the possible duplicate

Comment: Nop, not even using the solutions that question provided... It keeps giving me the error

Comment: Done everything possible. It just doesn't work!